# You must log in before using this part of Bugzilla, code:410

Tags: php, rest, authentication, curl, bugzilla

I am able to get the GET request working but having issues related to authentication in POST and PUT request. I am getting the error "You must log in before using this part of Bugzilla". I have provided the correct username and password. I have tried CURLAUTH_ANY as well as CURLAUTH_BASIC. I have tried both PUT and POST request. Any help is appreciated.

```
   $url ="http://localhost:8080/bugzilla/rest/bug/2";
   $apikey = "IZC4rs2gstCal0jEZosFjDBRV9AQv2gF0udh4hgq";
   $data = array(
            "product" => "TestProduct",
            "component" => "TestComponent",
            "version" => "unspecified",
            "summary" => "This is a test bug - please disregard",
            "alias" => "SomeAlias",
            "op_sys" => "All",
            "priority" => "P1",
            "rep_platform" => "All"
        );

  $str_data = json_encode($data);

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$str_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
                array("Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json")); 
 $username = 'ashish.sureka@in.abb.com';
 $password = 'abbincrc';
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
 curl_close($ch); 

 echo $result
```

Comment: You are declaring the API key variable but not using it.

Comment: `localhost:8080` ?

Comment: localhost:8080 is correct (no issue with this as my Bugzilla is configured to run at port 8080). I am able to invoke it from the browser and everything is ok, I am not using the API key, I have just declared it (I was just experimenting). The examples that I have seen on the web do not require API key and only username and password is enough. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

Following code solved my problem. I have [written a blog on it](http://ashish-sureka-delhi.blogspot.in/2016/09/invoking-bugzilla-rest-interface-from_16.html) which might be useful to others encountering the same problem.

```
       <?php

        $url = 'http://localhost:8080//bugzilla/xmlrpc.cgi';
        $ch = curl_init();

        $header = array(
            CURLOPT_URL     => $url,
            CURLOPT_POST    => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array( 'Content-Type: text/xml', 'charset=utf-8' )
        );
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $header);

        $bugreport = array(
            'login'       => 'ashish.sureka@in.abb.com',
            'password'    => 'abbincrc',
            'product'     => "TestProduct",
            'component'   => "TestComponent",
            'summary'     => "Bug Title :  A One Line Summary",
            'assigned_to' => "ashish.sureka@in.abb.com",
            'version'     => "unspecified",
            'description' => "Bug Description : A Detailed Problem Description",
            'op_sys'      => "All",
            'platform'    => "All",
            'priority'    => "Normal",
            'severity'    => "Trivial"
        );

        $request = xmlrpc_encode_request("Bug.create", $bugreport); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
        curl_exec($ch)

    ?>
```